# Fit image in EPPlus to total column width

Tags: image, epplus

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= columnArr.Length; i++)
{
    sheet.Column(i).AutoFit();
    totalWidth += sheet.Column(i).Width;
}
if (image != null)
{
    int percent = (int)(totalWidth*  100 / image.Image.Width);
    sheet.Row(1).Height = percent * image.Image.Height / 100;
    image.SetSize(percent);
}
```

I want this code should make `image` (of type `ExcelPicture`) be as wide as the columns in the relevant part of the sheet (in my case, 3 columns); however, the image is much smaller. However, the row does end up the correct height for the image as shown in the file. How can I fix the width of the image?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the other SetSize method.

```
SetSize(width, height)
```

Getting the details right was tricky but this worked for me:

```
report.Sheet.Column(columnIndex).Width = 10;
report.Sheet.Row(rowIndex).Height = 50;
picture.To.Column = picture.From.Column = columnIndex - 1;
picture.To.Row = picture.From.Row = rowIndex - 1;
picture.SetSize(70, 66);
```

Note that the column and row index is off by one.